# Rails model foreign key validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to validate the existence of a row referenced by a foreign key in one of my models. The situation is like this:

**Project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :project_category

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------
  # this does not work because the attribute is actually called 
  # 'category_id' instead of the rails expected 'project_category_id'
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------
  validates :project_category, presence: true
end
```

**Project Migration**

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|

      # ----------------------------------------------
      # this is why the column is called 'category_id'
      # ---------------------------------------------- 
      t.references :category, references: :project_categories, null: false

      # all of my other fields here, unimportant
    end
    add_foreign_key :projects, :project_categories, column: :category_id
  end
end
```

I know that I can write a custom validation method to check if the `:category_id` exists in the `project_categories` table but I would prefer to let rails handle the validation if there is a way, so I can keep my code DRY.

***EDIT***

**ProjectCategory.rb**

```
class ProjectCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

**ProjectCategory Migration**

```
class CreateProjectCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :project_categories do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you only need to add the `foreign_key` option to your `has_one` declaration in order to specify the custom column name you've specified i.e. `category_id` instead of `project_category_id`. See [Options for has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) for details.

```
# app/modeles/project.rb

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :project_category, foreign_key: 'category_id'

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------
  # this does not work because the attribute is actually called 
  # 'category_id' instead of the rails expected 'project_category_id'
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------
  validates :project_category, presence: true
end
```

Comment: After reading the docs and giving this a try it looks like `:foreign_key` option defines the name of a foreign key in the table which is passed to the `has_one` association. In that case I would need a `project_id` field in the `project_categories` table to use this option, which isn't how my schema is set up currently.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the two migrations and model relationships as they are setup.

Comment: If you have `belongs_to :project` in `project_categories` then you should add `project_id` foreign key to your `project_categories` model.

Comment: `project_categories` is just a lookup table. Am I missing something here? I don't want a new row in the `project_categories` table for every row in the `project` table.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you have foreign key in `projects` table that tells which `project_category` a `project` belongs to?  Is this correct?  Could you start a chat instead, I think it will be quicker to resolve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88733/discussion-between-steve-and-vee).